# how to create Job appliction form inside button in django using html,jquery css

Tags: jquery, html, css

http://127.0.0.1:8000/we_are_hiring/
Form Format created at frontend.
How to store the appliction in django at backend
and When i sumbit form action .html not found
.please tell how to create action.html
Thank you for advance

Answer (score 0):

We can't connect to a machine inside your network. Please host it somewhere else.